# Python networkx: Get all possible destinations for every node

Tags: python, graph, networkx

My graph wording might be off, apologies.
Given a directed graph, I'd like to get a dictionary where the key is a node, and the value is a set of all nodes that we can reach from this node using any path.
E.g on this graph:

```
1->2->3
4->5
```

We should get this result:

```
{
  1: set(2,3),
  2: set(3),
  3: set(),
  4: set(5),
  5: set(),
}
```

I could get that by calling something like this:

```
{n: networkx.bfs_tree(graph, n).nodes() for n in networkx.nodes(graph)}
```

But it implies O(n^2) iterations, while this could be built with O(n) iterations.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you can be sure it is an acyclic graph?  If so, do a topological sort first and you can probably get it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Optimization: we can reconstruct BFS from the connectivity tree of underlying nodes. So, recursive solution (acyclic graphs only):

```
d = {}
def foo(node):
    if node in d:
        return d[node]
    nodes = g.neighbors(node)
    d[node] = set(nodes)
    for neighbor in nodes:
        d[node].update(foo(neighbor))
    return d[node].union(nodes)
```

Test:

```
> _=[foo(node) for node in g.nodes()]
> d
{1: set([2, 3]), 2: set([3]), 3: set([]), 4: set([5]), 5: set([])}
```

Assuming cached calls are free, it should be O(e)

Comment: This will only fetch the direct neighbors, so in the example above `result[1] `will be `set(2)` and not `set(2,3)` as far as I can see.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read carefully enough. I will remove this answer and think again